# Why does the fulltext exact match bring up not matching entries?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm using mysql 5.7 with a query like:

```
select email from users where match(email) against ('+"yandex"' in boolean mode);
```

While it brings up good results, it also returns things like this:

```
soundexpert999@something.com
```

which only partially matches and gets the same score as `whatever@yandex.ru`. It seems to match anything including `ndex`.

But the documentation describes the quotes as "exact match"... so what's happening here?

Reproducer with mysql 5.7.31: (smallest string to cause it is `yand`)

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (`email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, FULLTEXT KEY `ngramtest` (`email`) WITH PARSER ngram);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> insert into foo values ('abc@yandex.com'), ('soundexpert999@something.com'), ('different');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select email from foo where match(email) against ('+"yandex"' in boolean mode);
+------------------------------+
| email                        |
+------------------------------+
| abc@yandex.com               |
| soundexpert999@something.com |
+------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select email from foo where match(email) against ('+"yand"' in boolean mode);
+------------------------------+
| email                        |
+------------------------------+
| abc@yandex.com               |
| soundexpert999@something.com |
+------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: That would be a very strange behaviour as fulltext searches cannot match a substring in the middle or at the end of a word, only at the beginning. Can you please create a test dataset on which we can check if we can reperform the issue you are encountering?

Comment: @Shadow added a repro example to the question.

Comment: @Shadow one bit not mentioned before is that I used the ngram parser

Comment: Then you have your answer... Just one question: why do you use ngram parser with European language if it explicitly says it was designed to work with ideographic languages that do not use word delimiters?

Comment: You really cannot expect it to work like the like operator. That's what you are trying to simulate here.